# how to make pull requests *without* a github account?

Tags: github, dvcs, pull, pull-request

One of the goals of git is to be decentralized. If Github is to be the ... hub of git, then maybe it could take into account that there are *other* hubs out there, and allow pull requests to happen on git URLs that are *not* hosted on github.

The [documentation](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/) is fairly clear about this: pull requests require that you have a Github account and that you fork a repository *on github*. Is this a real current technical limitation or is there a way to workaround that on Github?

If not, is it eventually planned to allow Github's "pull requests" tool to actually allow to pull from repositories outside of the Github silo?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`git request-pull`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-request-pull) to achieve the same kind of workflow (which is improved with Git1.7.9+).

See the article "[using signed tag in pull-requests](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-signed-tag-in-pull-requests.html)"

> A typical distributed workflow using Git is for a contributor to fork a project, build on it, publish the result to her public repository, and ask the "upstream" person (often the owner of the project where she forked from) to pull from her public repository. Requesting such a "pull" is made easy by the `git request-pull` command.

> Starting from Git release v1.7.9, a contributor can add a signed tag to the commit at the tip of the history and ask the integrator to pull that signed tag.
> When the integrator runs `git pull`:

> - the signed tag is automatically verified to assure that the history is not tampered with.

- In addition, the resulting merge commit records the content of the signed tag, so that other people can verify that the branch merged by the integrator was signed by the contributor, without fetching the signed tag used to validate the pull request separately and keeping it in the refs namespace.

---

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), "[`git request-pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ad7fd3cc0397bc8a030742aeb4a46b9354c06998/Documentation/git-request-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull))</sup> can strip embedded signature from signed tags using non-PGP signatures.

See [commit a9cad02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9cad02538a8e0518f000ad99099193d764fe795) (25 Jan 2023) by [Gwyneth Morgan (`gwymor`)](https://github.com/gwymor).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ad7fd3c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad7fd3cc0397bc8a030742aeb4a46b9354c06998), 08 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`request-pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9cad02538a8e0518f000ad99099193d764fe795): filter out SSH/X.509 tag signatures
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Gwyneth Morgan</sup>

> [`git request-pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a9cad02538a8e0518f000ad99099193d764fe795/Documentation/git-request-pull.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull))</sup> filters PGP signatures out of the tag message, but not SSH or X.509 signatures.

Comment: That's pretty cool for us civilized people that operate completely and naturally outside of github! :) However, that won't tell those people up in Github to pull my stuff. In fact, I am still unclear how I am supposed to ask "upstream": through email?

Comment: @anarcat you would send the email prepared by the git pull-request, through the "Compose message" of GitHub (https://github.com/inbox/new)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about request-pull: it is nice because it allows to work around a security issue with `git pull`... however, it does not interoperate with Github, which is what I was looking for originally...

Comment: @anarcat: if does "interoperate" by email to the upstream owner, but it won't register in the pull request queue of GitHub, if that is what you mean.

Comment: that is what i meant, indeed. any idea if this feature is planned?

Comment: @anarcat: no I do not know if that feature is planned. The workaround would be to clone your repo on GitHub itself, and do your pull request from there, but if you are *completely* outside GitHub, this isn't an option.